# Change UIView height with respect to UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, constraints

I have a View named AlarmView and a tableview named alarmtableview inside AlarmView , also I have a textfield 
Now What I want is when a user enters any number in textfield , tableview will be reloaded with number of rows equal to that number entered by the user.
I have set the AlarmView height as 0 initially , so that when the textfield is empty AlarmView remains invisible from the users.
And after reloading the alarmtableview , I am updating the detailview's  height  equal to tableview's height.
But when I run the app the view's height is not updated. it remains invisible from the users even after reloading the tableview

Below Is the code I have written to achieve the same

```
@IBOutlet weak var AlarmViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var AlarmView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var AlarmTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var FrequencyField: CustomUITextField!


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    print("textFieldDidEndEditing called")
    if textField === FrequencyField{
        self.AlarmToggleAction(self.AlarmSwitch)
    }
}
//MARK: ALARM Actions
@IBAction func AlarmToggleAction(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on{
        if let count = Int(self.FrequencyField.text!) {
            print("ON state")
            alarmCount = count
            AlarmTableView.reloadData()

            print("AlarmTableView.frame.height : \(AlarmTableView.frame.height)")
            AlarmViewHeightConstraint.constant = AlarmTableView.frame.height
        }
    }
    else{
        print("OFF state")
        alarmCount = 0
        //AlarmTableView.reloadData()
        //AlarmViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0

    }


}

//MARK: Tableview Actions
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSection called alarmCount : \(alarmCount)")

    return alarmCount
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   print("cellForRowAtIndexPath called")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AlarmCell") as! AlarmCell
        cell.TimeLabel.text = "Alarm \(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.TimeField.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.TimeSwitch.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
}
```

Please help me out of this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It will automatically done without any code if you have proper constraints

Comment: what should be the proper constraint for this

Comment: just pinned all edges and give >= height constraint to tableview

Comment: Using auto layout it will be easy just equal the height of detailview and tableview. Just hide or show the view on the basis of the conditions

Comment: Where is the delegate method implementation for tableview row height? do your height handling in this method and then you just need to reload tabledata

Comment: tried implementing row height delegate func but still not getting the results,

Comment: Try to give variable names starting from small letter, otherwise it seems you are calling `class methods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `contentSize` instead of frame size like:

```
AlarmViewHeightConstraint.constant = AlarmTableView.contentSize.height
```